# Absolute screen coordinates for nested CCNode tree

Tags: cocos2d-x

I tried to get real coordinates (like on iPad screen) for all elements on active scene using

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(node->getChildren(), obj)
```

for each Node I tried

```
CCPoint realCoordinates = node->getParent()->convertToWorldSpace(node->getPosition());
```

or this

```
CCPoint realCoordinates = node->convertToWorldSpace(node->getPosition());
```

or

```
CCPoint realCoordinates = node->convertToWorldSpaceAR(CCPointZero);
```

In result: For some node from my elements tree I have wrong coordinates.

Element tree is big in deep nested with anchors.

May be somthing can help me how can I calculate valid absolute (1024х768) screen coordinates for all elements from my CCNode tree.

Thanks

Comment: You should rather call `obj->getParent()->convertToNodeSpace(obj->getPosition())` rather than `node->getParent()->convertToWorldSpace()`

Comment: `node->getParent()->convertToWorldSpace(node->getPosition())` should work. It does for me.

Comment: Maybe you lastly want to call `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToUI(realCoordinates)` to get it in screen coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
node->getParent()->convertToWorldSpace(node->getPosition())
```

This worked for me for a button as a child of a listview in a child of a layout in the scene.

Seems like it should be working with you, too.

Comment: Counter-intuitive, but this works. I think it'd be much more ideal if this was a function on the node itself, rather than having to access the parent to call the function.